# Unable to build rgbdslam on groovy

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i followed the guide for building the package and everything run smooth till i reach the rosmake section that fails with this error

```
home/alessio/RosWorkspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/openni_listener.h:65:5: error: ‘signalMessage’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
/home/alessio/RosWorkspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/openni_listener.h:65:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/alessio/RosWorkspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/openni_listener.h:65:5: note: use ‘this->signalMessage’ instead
```

It seems like a problem with the source code... what am I doing wrong?

System description: ubuntu 12.10 64bit with ros-groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58633/unable-to-build-rgbdslam-on-groovy/) by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-19**:
Weird, because I have the same config as you, and I don't have the problem...
Have you tried to rosdep first ?

**Comment by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on 2013-03-20**:
yes and all the dependencies are installed...

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-26**:
hi, I am trying to install RGBDSLAM package on hydro. It says that follow the instruction on groovy first. But I cannot find a step by step one. Could you please give me a link?
Also, do you install the package in a catkin workspace or a rosbuild space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!,
it was some issue with the GCC compiler...
If you edit the /rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/openni_listener.h file changing from "signalMessage(...)" to "this->signalMessage(...)" it will compile without error.

---

Originally posted by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) with karma: 163 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-03-27**:
wtf? Sounds like something boost. I'll update the repository after easter.

**Comment by [fersarr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3210/fersarr/) on 2013-04-15**:
worked for me too, thanks Alex

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-04-17**:
I changed that in the repository. So it's not required to do this anymore. Thanks for sharing.